# Store JSON data received from a website hosted on github-pages

Tags: javascript, json, github, github-pages

So I am working on a [webpage](http://fossasia.github.io/open-event-android/) (hosted on github pages) where I need to convert the data entered by the user to a json object and then saving it to a file on the github repo for later use.

So far, I've converted the data to a json object, but I'm facing difficulty in storing this object to a .json file in my [github repository](https://github.com/fossasia/open-event-android/tree/gh-pages).

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe GitHub Pages only supports static pages. It unfortunately would not support such an action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MAttds17 said you will need a server side.

If your code will be simple, you can use a Backend as a service like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) or [Backand](https://www.backand.com).

If you think you will have heavy logic in your server side, you can host a real application in [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) or another alternative.